# call operator argument evaluation order

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

```
#include <string>

struct X
{
    char y;
    std::string z;

    X & operator()(std::string && s)
    {
        z = std::move(s);
        return *this;
    }

    X & operator()(char c)
    {
        y = c;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    X x;
    std::string y("abc");

    x(y[0])(std::move(y));
}
```

is the last line of `main` undefined behavior? I'm guessing yes because it would unfold to something like the following but just want to make sure that there are no stricter guarantees on call operators or member function invocations in general

```
X::operator()(&X::operator()(&x, y[0]), std::move(z))
```

---

Please add references from the standard or cppref

Comment: `I'm guessing yes because it would unfold to something like the following` I do not understand why the code presented would cause undefined behavior? Och, because `std::move(y)` may be executed before `y[0]` which would cause to access `y` after move which would be invalid?

Comment: Yes precisely. I know that arguments are evaluated indeterminately sequenced but as I'm asking not sure if that applies to these as well

Comment: also strictly speaking the `move` does not do anything, it is rather about the order of initializing the arguments ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before c++17, chaining function calls that modify the same l-value, like in your example, is indeed undefined behavior, since the order of evaluation of these expressions is unspecified.

However, a [proposal](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0145r1.pdf) to fix that was merged into c++17.

Here's the relevant [rule](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.call#8) (emphasis mine), which also contains an example from the proposal that shows how this works:

> **The postfix-expression is sequenced before each expression in the expression-list and any default argument.** The initialization of a parameter, including every associated value computation and side effect, is indeterminately sequenced with respect to that of any other parameter. [Note: All side effects of argument evaluations are sequenced before the function is entered (see [intro.execution]). — end note] [Example:
>
> ```
> void f() {
>  std::string s = "but I have heard it works even if you don't believe in it";
>  s.replace(0, 4, "").replace(s.find("even"), 4, "only").replace(s.find(" don't"), 6, "");
>  assert(s == "I have heard it works only if you believe in it");       // OK
> }
> ```
>
> — end example]

---

While the above rule only strictly refers to the built-in `operator()`, and you have user-defined operators, the same rules about order of evaluation apply, because of this [rule](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.oper#2):

> If either operand has a type that is a class or an enumeration, a user-defined operator function might be declared that implements this operator or a user-defined conversion can be necessary to convert the operand to a type that is appropriate for a built-in operator. ... **However, the operands are sequenced in the order prescribed for the built-in operator**.

Comment: I'd also cite https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.match.oper#2.sentence-4

Comment: @LanguageLawyer So expr.call only refers to in-built operators?

Comment: Yes, but for overloaded operators called in built-in operator form, subexpressions are evaluated the same way as for built-in operators.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Makes sense. Added to the answer.

Comment: There are no UB BTW, shrink happens only inside the operator call which happens last. `X& operator()(std::string s)` would be more problematic...

Comment: _So expr.call only refers to in-built operators?_ It is specified in https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.pre#3.sentence-1, BTW

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Oh, that's right, so it is. Thanks for pointing that out, the answer is much clearer as a result :)